# Can you receive emails through PHP?

Tags: php, email

I know you can send emails with PHP but, can you receive emails through PHP?

Comment: you can pipe incoming email to a php script, or as below imap.

Comment: Receive how? Do you for some reason want a SMTP server implementation in PHP, or do you want to just be notified of the received email into your PHP application?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can pipe incoming mails into a PHP script so you can process it directly. Evolt has an [article on how to setup](https://web.archive.org/web/20170830030931/http://evolt.org/incoming_mail_and_php) something like that. This can be useful if you want to activate scripts programmatically by sending Emails to it (like responses to a newsletter mail that unsubscribes the user).

If you just want to read mails using PHP, PHP has [native functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.imap.php) to talk to IMAP, NNTP and POP mailboxes.

Comment: Anyone know how to `pipe incoming emails into a PHP script` in a Windows Server environment?

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is broken, do you have any saved version by any chance?

Comment: @Amirmasoud Replaced the link with an archived version

Answer (score 3):

You *could* write a mail server in PHP that binds to a port and listens for incoming email.
But PHP is not the language I would recommend for tasks like this, and it would also be a hugely complex undertaking.

You can hook into an existing mail server as callback script, or periodically query a mail server via POP or IMAP. The latter option is the most common: run a PHP script that processes an email account via a cron task in intervals. See http://php.net/imap.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned PHP has traditional functions for IMAP and NNTP, but I do suggest using a simpler solution like using some external service that can provide attaching a custom domain and create email addresses to receive emails to. This is of course if you don't need to grab emails from providers such as Gmail, ProtonMail, etc.

I would suggest you to learn the following article about https://proxiedmail.com:

https://dev.to/yatsenkolesh/how-to-receive-email-with-php-3k21

We have a good PHP client with Laravel support that allows you to receive emails to your application via webhook or just by browsing the received emails list.

Please note that I'm a founder of the service and also it's paid, but email webhook is free for up to 200 received emails/day (then 9 USD/year).

Answer (score -2):

Only a mail server can receive e-mails. You could read mail box formats (such as mbox or Maildir) to read e-mail using PHP.

PHP scripts functioning as IMAP/POP3 servers can receive e-mail sent to them.

Comment: Eran Galperin: I never said PHP scripts *cannot* receive e-mail. What I said is that only mail servers can receive e-mail, which essentially means that the PHP script should act as a mail server to receive e-mails.

Comment: @Alan That's still incorrect, a script can receive an Email in raw form, it doesn't have to act as a mail server to do so. Just read the stdin input.

Comment: Eran Galperin: That is one option. I have stated reading mail box formats, which is another option.

Comment: You stated: only mail server can receive Emails - that is incorrect. PHP scripts don't have to act as IMAP or POP servers to receive Emails. Your answer is incorrect, except you point to an alternative to what the OP asked.

Comment: Eran Galperin: It is still correct. Only mail servers can **receive** e-mail. Others can **read** e-mail.

Comment: Incorrect: By definition, anything that can receive emails is a mail server, could be PHP or anything.