# Receive Emails into my Admin panel with php or other

Tags: php, email

I have a webpage and a admin panel.In website there is a contact form and report bug form which let users to send mail to my info@domain.com adress. By using Cpanel I'm able to see the mails but in my admin panel I have a email page that I can send mass emails to users and one by one. Is there a way to put an API or write a code to receive my info@domain.com mails into there. I dont want to enter cpanel to check the mails but use my admin panel to do them all. Couldn't reach anything like this on internet. Any ideas?

Comment: Read [How To Ask A Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is there email SMTP settings in cPanel? you can just use it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162847/can-you-receive-emails-through-php to receive mails and for sending mails you can use mail funciton. and you don't need of mail to manage the contact form, you can just save them to database and show them in admin panel using select queries.

Comment: @tonoslfx let me check out.

Comment: @PradeepKumarPrabaharan Im sending mails I need to receive.

Comment: the link is to receive mails please check. there are already questions for receiving mail in stackoverflow with answers. please check before asking here

Comment: Just install ***MS Outlook*** and configure `SMTP` and `POP3` or `iMAP` for your server.

Comment: I want to use my admin panel not my PC @mega6382

Comment: Then instead of using some custom php, use a tested and trusted `PHP webmail script`.

Comment: @mega6382 yes thats what im actually asking. What are those scripts are calling?

Comment: Look at these open source solutions https://github.com/jasonmunro/cypht or https://afterlogic.org/webmail-lite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can access you inbox from php. Please have a look at PHP's IMAP library: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php

Unlike the name suggests, this library can work with imap, pop3 and nntp so you should not have issues with accessing your inbox.

Comment: I will be checking to learn more about this. I will let you know Thank you.

Comment: Yes I solved my problem and established my mailbox into my admin panel Thank You. Currently I'm improving it.